# how to store symbolically the derivatives in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

my question relates to the Symbolic Math Toolbox from Matlab. I have the following code:

```
syms x x_0 u delta sigma_1
mu = sym ('mu(x)');
sigma_u = sym ('sigma(u)');
sigma = sym ('sigma(x)');
f = int (1/sigma_u, u, x_0, x);
df = subs(diff(f,x))
df_2 = subs(diff (f,x,2))
L = subs(mu*df+1/2*sigma^2*df_2)
```

The result of L is corect

```
L =

mu(x)/sigma(x) - diff(sigma(x), x)/2
```

However, for further derivations and for simplicity, I would like to define

```
sigma_1 = sym('diff(sigma,x)');
```

or in a similar way such as to get as result for

```
L =

mu(x)/sigma(x) - sigma_1(x)/2
```

Basically, I would like to store under a name the symbolic expression diff(sigma(x),x) such that Matlab knows that when it gets this result in a expression, to poste the name sigma_1 (x) instead of diff(sigma(x),x)

Comment: `f` is defined by means of an integral the Matlab is not able to evaluate; is that ok or not?

Comment: Hello. no, that is not the problem, Matlab cannot anyway evaluate the integral since the function sigma(u) is not explicitly defined. Matlab does a great job in applying Leibniz Rule in computing L (through df and df_2). However, I would just like that instead of having in the answer

Comment: diff(sigma(x), x) to have a name for the first serivative like sigma_1 which should stand for the first derivative of sigma wrt x and mostly I would like that sigma_1 to appear always in the program instead of diff(sigma(x), x). Subsequently, I would like to define similarly further higher order derivatives of the function sigma. Thank you

Comment: If you have the output it should not be too hard to replace this everywhere, why not simplify it afterwards? I think that what you ask may not be possible as you could also define sigma_2 in the same way and matlab would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can use `subs(L, 'diff(sigma(x),x)', 'sigma_1(x)')`.  Note to make the substitution work, the second input of `subs` must be exactly like what you want to replace;  hence it cannot be 'diff(sigma, x)' which lacks the `(x)` behind the `sigma`.

Also note that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822125/defining-relationship-for-symbolic-variable-in-matlab/20320825#20320825) is a similar question for which I provided a more complete solution (they asked the question after yours, but I read theirs first).