# Defining relationship for symbolic variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, relationship, symbolic-math

Let's say I have a symbolic variable "q" that depends on another symbolic variable "t".
This is how I define each symbolic variables.

```
t= sym('t');
q = sym('q(t)');
```

And I have an expression that contains this (when I use pretty(expression))

```
result = blah1* diff(q(t),t) *blah2
```

I want to make this particular part a new variable. Let's say "qdot"
In the end, I want it to be like this.

```
result2 = blah1*qdot*blah2
```

I'm in the process of figuring it out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `syms t q(t)`, 
`qdot = diff(q(t),t);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `subs` function.  Here is how to use it for your particular question

```
function Rewrite()
t = sym('t');
q = sym('q(t)');

a = sym('a');
blah1 = a^2;
blah2 = t^3;
result1 = blah1*diff(q,t)*blah2;

qDot = sym('qDot');
result2 = subs(result1, diff(q,t), qDot)
% result2 = a^2*qDot*t^3;
end
```

Note that

```
result2 = subs(result1, 'diff(q(t),t)', qDot)
```

and

```
newMiddle = sym('qDot');
result2 = subs(result1, diff(q,t), newMiddle)
```

also give the desired result.